# Alternative to using dp-width as discriminator for different layouts?

Tags: android, layout, resources, width

I'm creating an android application which is supposed to run on multiple different devices with notably different physical screen-sizes.
The recommended way to do this seems to be the discrimination of screen-sizes via the device's dp-width, eg creating a "layout-w700dp"-folder for the corresponding devices.

I tested my application on a Samsung galaxy Note 2 (5.5") and a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini (4.3"). They both display the layout differently due to the available space and thus need different layout files.

Here's the Problem: They both report a dp-width of 640. The Note has a dp-factor of 2 with a pixel-width of 1280, the S4 mini has a dp-factor of 1.5 with a width of 960px. How can I use different layout files for the devices? There's indubitably quite a huge difference in physical size and I quite honestly wonder for which reason the "Device Independent" measurement reports the same width for each device.

Is there any other way to use different layout-files per device?

Edit: I can't provide images of the application due to internal restrictions, but essentially I need to use different backgrounds for my buttons due to the fact that "wrap_content" takes the background-size (in pixels) into account, thus making them bigger on the S4 mini due to the lower density. If I don't, the buttons are too big on the S4 and overlap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much differently this layout is displayed on the two devices? Can you provide screenshots as well as the layout xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's indubitably quite a huge difference in physical size and I
>   quite honestly wonder for which reason the "Device Independent"
>   measurement reports the same width for each device

Definitely the two devices have the same screen size in dp. As the following:

1dp = 1px in 1.0 density screen, and

1dp = 1.5px in 1.5 density screen, and

1dp = 2.0px in 2.0 density screen.

so Note has 1280/2.0 = 640dp and mini has 960/1.5 = 640 dp. But you should always keep in mind that screen density is just a bucket which android engineers use to simplify the task for developers.That is , if a device is 180dpi, it has a density of 1.0, and a 220dpi screen will have a 1.5 density.

> Is there any other way to use different layout-files per device?

That seems impossible.

And last, if you want entire control over your layout, you can try building your views in java code with `DisplayMetrics`.(yes, it is surely not a good approach).

Comment: I am aware that the match checks out, I'm just surprised that the density value delivered by the android-framework which has the sole purpose to accommodate for different screen-sizes and resolutions is that unspecific (eg. the bucket size is that big). Should it really be expected from a developer to handle a 4.3" and a 5.5" screen the same way? I'm gonna solve my problem by specifying everything in dp and using the same layout on both devices. There will be no visual bugs anymore, but neither will I be able to make use of the Note's spare real estate.

Comment: Actually, I think the engineers may want us to use the same layout in these two devices